# 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. (in comand prompt)

Tags: windows, git, command-line

windows command prompt can't seem to recognize git.
Even if I enquired the version via (git --version), it keeps saying git is not recognized. I don't know if my machine has git installed. I was also to clone my git hub repo to my machine, but git is not working in my computer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command%2C+operable+program+or+batch+file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that git is not installed. In this case you will need to install it.

Try finding git, see https://eu.siteground.com/kb/install-git-windows-machine/

If you find git, then add it to PATH, see https://linuxhint.com/add-git-to-path-windows/

It is also possible that git is installed with another user and you do not have access to it with your user. Try finding out whether that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have git installed on your machine I think.
Try installing it :)

Answer (score 1):

- if Git is not installed, install and check.
- if git installed, then try to

  - close the current command prompt and reopen.
  - refresh the computer once.